# How to Implemet onClick listener insidie Recycleview to open different activities

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm using Horizontal Recycleview to show the icon in my app. It cotains one Recycle view and one Mainactivity Class.

I'm trying to use the onClick listener method inside the adapter class   but to my surprise it is not working yet all and also don't recognize intent and give cannot resolve intent symbol. so I used toast message instead but also app  compile sucessfully but nothing happens.

Here is my Recycle view class

```html
public class SnapRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SnapRecyclerAdapter.ReyclerViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public SnapRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ReyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);

        return new ReyclerViewHolder(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ReyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = items.get(position);

        holder.image.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
        holder.appName.setText(item.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ReyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView appName;

        private ReyclerViewHolder(final View v) {
            super(v);

            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            appName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            context = v.getContext();
        }


        private View.OnClickListener Click=new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(getAdapterPosition())
                {
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No data available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        };
    }

}
```

and my Mainactivity class is

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        createApps();

        SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        // HORIZONTAL for Gravity START/END and VERTICAL for TOP/BOTTOM
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        SnapRecyclerAdapter adapter = new SnapRecyclerAdapter(this, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void createApps() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item("Google+", R.drawable.google_plus));
        items.add(new Item("Facebook", R.drawable.facebook));
        items.add(new Item("LinkedIn", R.drawable.linkedin));
        items.add(new Item("Youtube", R.drawable.youtube));
        items.add(new Item("Instagram", R.drawable.instagram));
        items.add(new Item("Skype", R.drawable.skype));
        items.add(new Item("Twitter", R.drawable.twitter));
        items.add(new Item("Wikipedia", R.drawable.wikipedia));
        items.add(new Item("Whats app", R.drawable.what_apps));
        items.add(new Item("Pokemon Go", R.drawable.pokemon_go));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bir - could you reduce this to a minimal viable reproducible example?  As is this is quite a lot of code to work through.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the click listener on the whole `itemView`? Here is an example:

```
//Implement View.OnClickListener
class ReyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView appName;

    private ReyclerViewHolder(final View v) {
        super(v);

        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        appName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_name);

        // Set the onClickListener
        v.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // if (getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
              Context context = v.getContext();
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, aActivityClass.class);
              intent.putExtra(extraKey, extraValue);
              context.startActivity(intent)
        // }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation `setOnClickListener` is not correct. You should set it for each view in `RecylerView` and inside that you can write your code to start an activity or show a toast, etc.

```
public class SnapRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SnapRecyclerAdapter.ReyclerViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public SnapRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ReyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);
        ReyclerViewHolder holder = new ReyclerViewHolder(item)
        item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO: You can start an activity by using Intent as well.
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ReyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = items.get(position);

        holder.image.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
        holder.appName.setText(item.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ReyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView appName;

        private ReyclerViewHolder(final View v) {
            super(v);

            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            appName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            context = v.getContext();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It was very much kindful of you to help me..I did as you  suggested but I'm getting error at  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { where view is highlighted in red and says can't resolve the view. Here is the screenshot  https://ibb.co/cwB4Ze

Comment: @BirNepali please change `view` to `item`.

Comment: Umm Rajshri answer solved the problem. but anyway I'll vote your answer as helpful.

Comment: You can go back this code if you encounter with any issues later.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the click listener on a `View` ? Something like `image.setOnClickListener(Click)` ? By the way, variables should start with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the view from adapter by using onclickListner and make and internface in adapter

this is where we are passing the view in adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myholder holder, final int position) {
    holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.click(position,view);
        }
    });
```

Interface for adapter onclick and activity:

```
public void clickItem(PartnerBankAdapter.OnItemClick onItemClick){
this.onItemClick=onItemClick;
}
public interface OnItemClick{
public void click(int postion,View view);
}
```

Define Interface as glocbal object in adapter:

```
private OnItemClick onItemClick;
```

Consider this example for adapter:

```
public class PartnerBankAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PartnerBankAdapter.myholder> {

public Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> bankname;
ArrayList<Integer> iconlist;
private OnItemClick onItemClick;
public PartnerBankAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> banklist,ArrayList<Integer> iconlist)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.bankname=banklist;
    this.iconlist=iconlist;


}

@Override
public myholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bank_list_adpater,parent,false);
    return new myholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myholder holder, final int position) {
    holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.click(position,view);
        }
    });
   holder.txt.setText(bankname.get(position));
   holder.image.setImageResource(iconlist.get(position));
   holder.txtacc.setText(bankname.get(position));
}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bankname.size();
}
public  static  class myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txt,txtacc;
    ImageView image;
    LinearLayout parent;
    public myholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
            txt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txbank);
            image=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagebank);
            parent=(LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            txtacc=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txbankacc);

    }
}
public void clickItem(PartnerBankAdapter.OnItemClick onItemClick){
    this.onItemClick=onItemClick;
}
public interface OnItemClick{
    public void click(int postion,View view);
}
}
```

and then just use onclick in your activity on recyclerview

consider code below for onclick in activity :

```
partnerBankAdapter.clickItem(new PartnerBankAdapter.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void click(int postion, View view) {
 }
});
```